# What is the pythonic way to calculate equations with different roots?

Tags: python, math

I have an equation `((1 -/+ p)/6) % p`, which I need to run for a couple million values of `p`.

The code I currently have is

```
primes = [5,7,11,13,17,19,23,29,31,37,41,43,47,
          53,59,61,67,71,73,79,83,89,97]

if __name__ == "__main__":

    for p in primes:

        print ((1 - p)/6) % p, ((1 + p)/6) % p
```

which, as expected, gives me

```
4 1
6 1
9 2
11 2
14 3
16 3
19 4
24 5
26 5
31 6
34 7
36 7
39 8
44 9
49 10
51 10
56 11
59 12
61 12
66 13
69 14
74 15
81 16
```

What I'd like to know is how to get

```
1
6
2
11
3
16
4
5
26
31
7
36
8
9
10
51
56
12
61
66
14
15
81
```

I haven't really tried anything yet, I've tossed around the idea of using a generator. However, in doing so I'm not sure if I am going to run into performance issues.

Comment: Do you want to print the first number twice? Then just put it twice! What does it have to do with generators?

Comment: @rodrigo I'm going to run it a couple million times... factorials get expensive after a couple millions times, the factorial won't be there. It is only there now for illustrative purposes. I will remove it.

Comment: How did you find those 'solutions'?

Comment: We have no idea why you're choosing one answer or the other from each pair.

Comment: "I'm not sure if I am going to run into performance issues." Then try it and see if you have performance issues. If you do, *profile* and fix the slow bits. If you can't fix the slow bits, ask a question on StackOverflow, detailing what's slow, how you've tried to fix it and what went wrong. "Premature optimization is the root of all evil (or at least most of it) in programming." --Donald Ervin Knuth

Comment: `print`ing is more or less computationally expensive. You should avoid printing a couple of million values and just save the information you wish to derive from this program -- to be printed out later.

Comment: You have to be aware that your question, as is, makes no sense. You want to print just one of the two numbers in every row, but what is the criterion? You give no clue other than a passing reference to factorials...

Answer (score 3):

Is this what you are looking for?

```
for p in primes:
    r1=f(p - 4) % p
    r2=((1 - p)/6) % p
    if r2==r1:
        print r1, r2
    else:
        print r1, ((1 + p)/6) % p
```

When you say you haven't really tried anything yet, don't try and optimize it yet! Just get something that produces what you want -- THEN worry about using a generator or performance issues.

Edit:

You changed your question substantially, and it is not clear what you are looking for anymore. If you are looking for root finding, [here is some code](http://www.math-cs.gordon.edu/courses/mat342/python/findroot.py).

[Scipy](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/optimize.html#module-scipy.optimize) also has many root finding methods.

Pick a direction -- get something running -- THEN try and fix it if it is too slow.

Comment: You should get a 'telepathic' badge for this answer